# How to find height of the contents of an iFrame? (Cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to figure out either the height of the contents within an iFrame (this is hosted on a different domain that I don't have access to). I need to know when a user clicks on a link within the iFrame and when the page re-sizes.

I've been searching around for a while and it seems like I need to have access to the source code of the iFrame source, can anyone confirm if this is true or not? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do without access to the source code of the child page?

So far I've tried to access the contents of the iFrame directly via jquery and using a postMessage. Neither of these methods worked.

Thanks!

Comment: You do indeed need access to the source of the iframe to do this, which requires you to have access to the server that generates the source. You're out of luck.

Comment: http://www.jquery4u.com/dom-modification/jquery-change-css-iframe-content/

Comment: Its impossible. You can't access content of iframe outside of it. But you can access a content from a page inside a iframe.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the responses.